# Microsoft Visual Studio was automatically closed during the installation of an update

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I **often** get the following message while working on VS2015. What's worst is that it shutdowns the entire machine and restarts the machine that, of course, means all open programs are closed, unsaved data is lost, all programs need to be re-open: **Question**: What is the cause of the issue and what may be a possible fix?

**Environment**:

1. System: Windows 10 (upgraded from Win 7)
2. VS2015 with most recent updates (Update 3 etc.)

[image]

Comment: so whats the question?

Comment: @SimonPrice I've added a question that I thought was implicit in the original post since the post says it happens **often**.

Comment: @Filburt that may be the case, but when searching online for answers, this is the only one that pops up.